# text-overflow: ellipsis is not working in jsf selectOneMenu and also in SelectItem

Tags: java, jsf

I have a drop down select box. I want to use ellipsis in that drop down list. I have selectOneMenu and inside that I have a selectItems. My Question is how use ellipsis in selectItems?? I already tried with style and styleClass. but it won't work. any help appreciate..
Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you share some code with us to understand that what you want to do.

Comment: <h:selectOneMenu id="selectOneMenuID" value="#{bean.selectedIndex}" style="width: 100%;font-size:11px;">       
 <f:selectItems value="#{bean.beanItems}"/> 
</h:selectOneMenu>

Answer (score 1):

The `<f:selectItem>` in `<h:selectOneMenu>` generates a HTML `<option>` element. That element has in CSS very restrictive styling options. The only which works crossbrowser is the font color. For the remaining, and that is not really much (at most background color, font weight and text decoration), the support depends on the browser make/version.

Your best bet is really to abbreviate the value yourself and append the character [U+2026](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm) `…`. Otherwise you need to grab some JSF component library or even some jQuery plugin which turns a `<select><option>` element into a `<div><ul><li>` which allows you full CSS freedom. PrimeFaces for example has a `<p:selectOneMenu>` which does exactly that.

An alternative is to just not use "very long" option labels, or to use CSS (and in IE also JS) to give the select element a fixed width, but the options list still the (default) full width.

Comment: If there was, I'd have mentioned it.